# Calculate Connection flight path with google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to find something similar to my problem, however, I was not able to find anything useful. I am working on a reservation system, where you can book individualized charter flights.

Using the google maps api, I can click on one airport (which is a google maps marker) and then click on the next one, and so on, building my flight route.

I store the distances, marker coordinates, etc. in different arrays, so i can create a route.

Naturally, an Airplane has limited fuel. So if I want to do a long flight, I have to do a **connection stop** in between.

So if I click on A, and B is out of reach, I want google maps to calculate/show me the shortest possible route. So it will be A -> B -> C.

I think it is also worth mentioning, that several airports will be in between. But optimally I want the quickest connection.

I know the airplane can only fly 3 hours, and thus I can calculate the distance between two points, I know if the arrival airport is out of reach.

Optimally already also drawing the route. It should look something like this:  [example of route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brw5.png)

is there any recommendable approach to accomplish this ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you were going from La Paz to Brasilia, which would be the shortest route?

Comment: Hi Duncan, it would be the marker next to it. The picture is just a random example. But to ilustrate:  So if I were to fly from Santa Cruz (like in the picture)  to Brasilia. The plane would have to stop in the airport which is between the two markers, just as shown in the example. The algorithm has to know that the airport in between is the shortest route.